# Is $ X \to \mathrm{CH}^i (X) $ covariant or contravariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $ X $ be a scheme of finite type over $k$.

Let $ \mathrm{CH}^i(X)$ be the Chow group of $ \ i \ $ cocycles on $X$.

- Is $ X \to \mathrm{CH}^i (X) $ a covariant or a contravariant functor ? Why ?

Let $ \mathrm{CH}_i(X)$ be the Chow group of $ \ i \ $ cycles on $X$.

- Is $ X \to \mathrm{CH}_i (X) $ a covariant or a contravariant functor ? Why ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looking at Wikipedia, the group of dimension $i$-cocycles is a covariant functor for proper morphisms, and also covariant for flat morphisms (although with a shift in degree.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pullback of a divisor is not always well-defined. For example, if $f : X \to \Bbb P^1$ is a constant map, then the pullback of a point could be $[X]$  or $0$. But if $f : X \to Y$ is a flat morphism then there is a pullback map $f^*$ which is contravariant.

On the other hand the pushforward is better behaved (we still ask $f$ to be proper). The definition is a bit tricky so I write it here for convenience : if $f : X \to Y$ and $Z \subset X$ is a closed subvariety then we define $f_*([Z]) := 0$ if $\dim f(Z) < \dim Z$, $n [f(Z)]$ if $\dim f(Z) = \dim Z$ and the restriction $f_{|Z} : Z \to f(Z)$ has degree $n$, and extend by linearity. This time this is covariant.

See 1.3.6, chapter on the Chow ring, section "Functoriality" in the book by Eisenbud and Harris, "*3264 and all that*". If you are looking for proof I think you need to look at the book by Fulton on intersection theory.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas. ;-)

Comment: @YoYo : My pleasure ! :-)

Comment: @YoYo (and @NicolasHemelsoet) Proofs of these facts are avalaible also [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf) (Chapter 9).